# progressdialog bar not working

Tags: android, file-upload, progressdialog, android-progressbar

im uploading files and im trying to use progressbar while its uploading

frist of all i start the upload with this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(upload.this);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.setMessage("Subiendo Archivo...");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setProgress(0);
            dialog.show();

            //dialog.show(upload.this,"","Subiendo Archivo...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(upload.this,"Escoge un archivo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

then uploadFile(selectedFilePath); starts here is my code:

```
//android upload file to server
    public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        File sourceFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
        int totalSize = (int)sourceFile.length();


        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
            dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }else{
            try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);


               int totalBytesWritten = 0;


                        //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                        while (bytesRead > 0) {

                            //write the bytes read from inputstream
                            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                                totalBytesWritten += bytesRead;


                            if (dialog != null) {
                                dialog.setProgress((int)(totalBytesWritten/ totalSize * 100));
                            }

                        }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvFileNames.setText("Sigue el link para ver tu archivo:");
                            tvFileName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"https://cloud.dattasolutions.com.mx/app/uploads/" + fileName + "\"><font color=\"red\">" + fileName + "</font></a> "));
                            tvFileName.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                           // tvFileName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            //tvFileName.setText("Escoger otro archivo");
                            ivAttachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            vView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            tvFileNames.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ivAttachment.setImageResource(R.drawable.attach_icon);
                            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = ivAttachment.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.width = 300;
                            layoutParams.height = 300;
                            ivAttachment.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                            //POSISION TEXTO
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.ivAttachment);
                            params.setMargins(0, 73, 0 ,0);
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tv_file_names);
                            params1.setMargins(0, 123, 0 ,0);
                            tvFileNames.setLayoutParams(params);
                            tvFileName.setLayoutParams(params1);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Archivo subido correctamente!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();


                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(upload.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(upload.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(upload.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

    }
```

the problem is here:

```
int totalBytesWritten = 0;


                        //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                        while (bytesRead > 0) {

                            //write the bytes read from inputstream
                            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                                totalBytesWritten += bytesRead;


                            if (dialog != null) {
                                dialog.setProgress((int)(totalBytesWritten/ totalSize * 100));
                            }
```

exactly here:

> if (dialog != null) {
>                                       dialog.setProgress((int)(totalBytesWritten/ totalSize * 100));
>                                   }

proggress bar is on 100% all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate or in your onClick if you want you should new up a Handler

```
Handler mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.prepareMainLooper());
```

then you can use

```
private void updateUI(){
     mMainHandler.post(new Runnable(){
         //touch dialog
     }
}
```

Comment: i used part of your code but its freezes like progressbar percentage 14/100 i have another explanation over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559312/progressdialog-bar-get-freeze

Comment: Yes it does matter when you are calling the updates. You are calling from a background thread and want to make sure that you are not updating every millisecond for example. If you are updating too often it can get frozen